# how to navigate one navigation graph to another in android jet pack navigation controller

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack

I have two navigation graph one for registration of my application after completing registration I want to navigate another graph is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use startActivity method to navigate to another navigation 
eg :

`activity?.startActivity(Intent(activity,HomeActivity::class.java))` in kotlin

`getActivity().startActivity((Intent(getActivity(),HomeActivity.class))` in java

Note : **HomeActivity** contains nav host of another navigation graph